# I don't know how to store a large number of large numbers represented as a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, data-structures, biginteger

I am doing a university project on a subject of algorithms and data structures in which I have to work with very large integers and perform operations with them.
I have implemented the numbers as strings and then I have implemented the different functions for the operations.
The problem is when the number of input data is too large that the application keeps running without giving any errors.

I have tried to understand the reason why this happens and I have made a small main in which I only take the big numbers as strings and store them in a dynamic array and then print them, but even that keeps running without stopping.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int numOfNumbers;
    int numbersAdded=0;
    string input;
    string * arrayStrings;

    cin>>numOfNumbers;
    arrayStrings = new string[numOfNumbers];

    while(numbersAdded<numOfNumbers){
        cin>>input;
        arrayStrings[numbersAdded]=input;
        numbersAdded++;
    }

    for( int i = 0;i<numOfNumbers;i++){
        cout<<arrayStrings[i]<<endl;
    }
    delete arrayStrings; 
    return 0;
}
```

An example of an entry that gets you caught is:

```
100
1755128662250792726817307299021171022405
31602321932429919472347573932692115431
268613145625556
250995805115735123
2899821022216164821112051434821414118992115
27037278211962523201109134711837128617
279861141430143181518313
2556629007151952158131140
1196912232195651587224241
25217152742925013174325932918818704
127821054
253383867323001191423791
12348974130864
244901178019747324332994326262233310788
18871141121893613802910810566
298051220827966
22834322993767274181806121073176276959
12172351826990186206862376618791364
265732764173081220829716267442977319643273552225
24918204792116219043248262793915692401
1305831542
30700176671024343283713253592324315123
9631
1804116485164091127419645307015708
29922293842728930729216901755925702294991697
312452939618283102002333813782
97001726910215
23089
2228413461326671224530389
50281073851141324619663888524356
205537847
4387273422883676941299220683242529040
1068826033659423960273693499146131576
2353678092237010742
567428219113142508327393933916217
17519165136816290383310
171663253627992516622113674
13381174435173157252769015538248512802226982
18939548432449863556502935431668
227241606761772096923316172751849825321
28694
261158777214625061325511618639
26145245508605217823270225534
9144465612451
402063232412328332621313454157147811593510403
2974732438266188181
1971018749
2608143554273201627901930612227
167113264813914100695502
239491554826951684320992306102348527205832624426
322822701797512490321722
1222658617674291042489030110130720373
1918462976913296498889758915077263829448
272293167524341951427352662028327883857012375
174729150
1883623593305601460321897187512426209633019
8429505540641879120482112152815831074
2911590820561533087024079274326803
231262255129369314921398
30218
6853262887099
2979341273197322453071355192052510086228731082
6438195802600523532253931662830115
21455231162900119942
1839328344472262818266
2268711331105532851514258226702715029956686
1381271732204670982604920683
1750956011825180313080759535309
18306484
16752289242081714613984029594732346411804
269183243217101651922759
131903520
229283615302493931
25763
364627483502384441528056209239724
354632628
3536258474331130602772228026
287381151832596
28131307231326253372981510017858241118521
169071469721153
7226251212711565303162629173113572719
258312380924193826615620250272436820120
160731153614188
2355415899121291505218690251982485
2945329191793126217
199711279824919481281127503728828878916664
1846726425647269211818
2465830451616236642298932066180323217722337
2429926243493098211362313209
165211048224556263776021
7241210514
225393969266532086311050200721609924062
2391931833136282025125495
2211530320
15811209652225412597
104015738152769143240341892186871702212318
101430481142326694
327164589132301399725305
606829769525
136531485572681027581483494522825242
```

Comment: `delete arrayStrings;` invokes *undefined behavior*  - you allocated with `new[]`, not `new`

Comment: Why are you _not_ using `std::vector` of `std::string` i.e. `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Are you making this hard on yourself as an academic exercise (a valid reason)? If the point of your work is not to implement multi precision integer arithmetic, use a library that already exists and get to the important part of your work. `boost::multiprecision` would handle this. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints.html

Comment: Works fine, when you fix the bug mentioned by UnholySheep. `delete arrayStrings;` -> `delete[] arrayStrings;`. What do you mean with _"the application keeps running without giving any errors."_ sounds like a good thing to me.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I can't use existing structures, the task says "You should implement your own data structures (you should not use STL library, vector, etc.)."

Comment: In that case, if you're not already headed in that direction, make your own `BigInteger` class.

Comment: @churill I just fixed the bug but when I say that it hangs is that it never  prints the output and it doesn't stop running, it should print and finish, not? Sorry I don't have much idea.

Comment: You mean it keeps asking for input? I thought I had encountered a similiar bug in your code, but I just forgot to press enter after the last number. Then it printed all the numbers and finished as expected.

Comment: You're most likely expected to implement a class for representing big numbers, and without using `std::string`. (This is mostly an exercise in array handling and memory management.)

Comment: @churill I have done just this but for me it doesn´t print nothing. I have used the debugger and when I occurs when I add the 36 number

Comment: @molbdilo yes i think so , the subject is algorithms and data structures, but I am not even able to store the data as an array of strings. I thought that first I want to understand how to do this and then use objects representing Big Numbers to perform the operations.

Comment: Your specific problem is you're not clearing a `cin` error caused when it tries to parse a large number into a signed 32-bit integer with a max of 2147483647. This causes the `cin` in the while loop to immediately return, not taking any user input but the loop continues until numOfNumbers reaches the integer max 2147483647.  As others have pointed out, you could use vectors and a bit of validation to reduce your code and tidy up (see my answer with a new implementation and a fix).

Comment: @jooshmoo maybe try with a smaller example, like 2 or 3 numbers. I sadly can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I just ran the code you posted and (as long as you change `delete arrayStrings;` to `delete [] arrayStrings;` It seems to run perfectly fine on the input you provided.  (100 entries) So what's the current problem?  Is it just what happens when the user inputs a `numOfNumbers` that is larger than what is representable by a 32-bit int?

Comment: @Wyck yes you are right I just used an online C++ compiler and it works without any errors. Nevertheless when I run the same program on Xcode it doesn´t work , so I suppose that is a problem of XCode maybe

Comment: Thank you all for your responses:)

Comment: Maybe it didn't recompile correctly and you were running an old executable? Good luck for your further investigation :)

Comment: What is the text of the first line of the input file that FAILS?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is but it's related to XCode because I run the app from terminal and it works fine so I don't know what is wrong. Thanks so much for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use string to store number. In you context strings will take more space and will be slow to operate upon.

Lets say, you want to store the number 12345678901234567890. Now if you want to store this number using string you will need 20 bytes(8 bit char is used). 
    String s = "12345678901234567890";

Instead of that you can use array of unsigned integer. In most of the modern compiler and computer architecture integer is of 4 byte. so they can represent numbers till 4,294,967,295.
Now lets consider largest number is decimal(all digits are nine) that can be represented by unsigned integer is 999,999,999. If you use array of integer now you will only need 3 integers. which is 12 bytes.
    unsigned int number[] = {234567890, 345678901, 12};

Now consider simple arithmetic operation addition.
    unsigned int number1[] = {123456789, 123456789};
    unsigned int number2[] = {987654321, 987654321};
now if you want to add above two number you will only have 2 iteration to get your answer.

you can still further compress done memory foot print if you got at bit level. It would be bit tedious job but you will get best performance.

Comment: I think the point of the task is to specifically work with number that _don't_ fit into an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response I will try to implement it with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Your specific problem:**

The problem you're hitting is that when you enter a number larger than a signed integer can hold, `cin` is put into error state. This means subsequent calls to `cin` don't work until you call `cin.clear()`.

Read about it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/

To fix your code try adding `cin.clear()` after calls to `cin` like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int numOfNumbers;
int numbersAdded=0;
string input;

/* todo: use a vector<string> instead - which handles resizing and allocation for you */
string * arrayStrings;

if (!(cin >> numOfNumbers))
{
    cout << "Warning: cin failed, did you enter a number larger than an numOfNumbers can hold? Value stored: " << numOfNumbers << endl;

    /* todo: maybe stop execution here and report back? */

    /* this will reset cin and leave numOfNumbers holding the largest value it can */
    cin.clear();
}

arrayStrings = new string[numOfNumbers];
/* todo: check the allocation succeeded, otherwise stop and report the error */

while(numbersAdded<numOfNumbers){
    if (!(cin >> input))
    {
        cout << "Warning: input failed, you entered a valid string? Value stored: " << input << endl;

        /* this will reset cin and leave input holding the largest value it can */
        cin.clear();
    }

    arrayStrings[numbersAdded]=input;
    numbersAdded++;
}

for( int i = 0;i<numOfNumbers;i++){
    cout<<arrayStrings[i]<<endl;
}

/* todo: this only deletes the array of pointers, not the strings themselves. Use a vector instead to avoid having to do memory management. */
delete arrayStrings; 
return 0;
}
```

Running the above program will give you the following output when a large number is entered:

> 99999999999999999999999999999
>   Warning: cin failed, did you enter a number larger than an numOfNumbers can hold Value stored: 2147483647

**A better approach:**

As others pointed out in comments there are other things to tidy up here too, using vectors etc. Here's an alternative implementation that's cleaner and has more validation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    unsigned int numOfNumbers;
    vector<string> numberStrings;

    cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter?" << endl;
    if (cin >> numOfNumbers)
    {
        unsigned int i;

        /* input numbers from console */
        cout << endl << "Please enter " << numOfNumbers << " numbers:" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++)
        {
            string input;
            cin >> input;
            numberStrings.push_back(input);
        }

        /* print numbers out */
        cout << endl << "You entered:" << endl;
        for (const auto& num: numberStrings)
        {
            cout << num << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Number of numbers must be a positive integer less than " << UINT_MAX << endl;
    }

    return 0;
} /* vector magically deallocates when it leaves scope */
```

Answer (score 0):

Tangentally, and generally-unrelated to the above:  "and if you need to store 'anything' as a string," you can always use JSON, YAML, or XML.  These formats are portable, self-describing, and readily available.